# How to get the implicit port from an embedded Neo4j database?

Tags: java, neo4j

Given one starts an embedded database:

```
BoltConnector boltConnector = new BoltConnector("bolt");
new GraphDatabaseFactory()
  .newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(Files.createTempDirectory("part-relasjon").toFile())
  .setConfig(boltConnector.enabled, "true")
  .setConfig(boltConnector.type, "BOLT")
  .setConfig(boltConnector.listen_address, "localhost:0")
  .newGraphDatabase();
```

how do I get hold of the port to which the database is bound? I want to create a `Driver` to connect to the database:

```
GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost:?")
```

I am doing this to run integration tests in a specific application profile. Right now, I find a free port manually and bind the server and driver to it, but I am looking for a way of extracting it from the randomly selected port as it seems like the cleaner solution. I had a look into the `Neo4jRule` from the test package to see how it is done there but the latter bootstraps a server what is much more complex than the above code which is why I want to avoid it.

Answer (score -1):

This is an example from the documentation here : https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/3.3/#tutorials-java-embedded-bolt

```
GraphDatabaseSettings.BoltConnector bolt = GraphDatabaseSettings.boltConnector( "0" );

GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory()
        .newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder( DB_PATH )
        .setConfig( bolt.type, "BOLT" )
        .setConfig( bolt.enabled, "true" )
        .setConfig( bolt.address, "localhost:7687" )
        .newGraphDatabase();
```

As you can see, here, you define the port (here `7687`, the default one).

You can find a free port by yourself in java via something like that :

```
InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress( 'localhost', 7687 );
new ServerSocket( addres.getPort(), 100, address.getAddress() ).close();
```

If you got an exception, port is not free.

It seems that since the version `3.3`, you can define to `0` the port of any connector, and Neo4j will find a free port.

To know the port, you can try this java code (comes from here : https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/3.4/community/neo4j-harness/src/main/java/org/neo4j/harness/internal/InProcessServerControls.java):

```
server.getDependencyResolver().resolveDependency( ConnectorPortRegister.class ).getLocalAddress( "bolt" ).getPort();
```

Cheers

Comment: But I want/need a random free port.